# C# Regex Ignoring Escaped Character

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this that is delimited `|` and can contain any character in between:

```
"one two|three four five|six \| seven eight|nine"
```

I'd like to find a regex that returns:

```
one two
three four five
six | seven eight
nine
```

I can think about how I want to do this but, I don't know regex well enough.  I basically want to match until I reach a `|` that is not preceded by a `\`.  How do I do this?  I know there is a back tracker, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially you want to find instances of this pattern:

```
@"([^|\\]|\\.)+"
```

This matches:

1. `[^|\\]` — Any character aside from a pipe or a backslash.
2. `\\.` — Any character escaped with a backslash.
3. `(...|...)+` — One or more of the preceding (escaped) characters.

The `\\.` construct is nice because it lets you escape any character, in particular other backslashes. This lets you have a backslash at the end of a string, for example:

```
"backslash \\|forward slash /|pipe \|"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Split(input, @"(?<!\\)\|");
```

- `(?<!\\)` - negative lookbehind.  There is no preceding `\`

Comment: a single negative look behind does not parse an even number of preceding backslashes correctly. E.g. input:  first \\| second<br> should return: first \\, then second